# Listing files 100 per each press in linux

Tags: linux, bash, list, file

There are thousands of files in one directory in my linux system.

How can I list 100 files per each press?
like, at first it will show first 100 files, then after pressing any key or enter key, it will show next 100 files, and so on.

Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `less` or `more` (pipe the output of your listing of the directory to these), e.g.

```
ls | less
```

or

```
ls | more
```

which will even allow you to move upwards again within the entire list of files. You can use (page up) and (page down) keys to skip an entire screen.

Another possibility is entering a number and `j` afterwards, e.g. `100j`. This will make less skip through 100 lines, cf. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but still slow, like one per press! and for stop showing somewhere in the middle, i tried ':q'. Is there any other keyboard command for stop showing list.

Comment: Or even some other pager like `most`, or perhaps running the shell under `emacs` (or using its `dired-mode`), etc etc... Learn how to configure and use your pager program (e.g. `less` with `~/.lessrc` etc...)

Comment: @SaifulIslam You only need to type `q` to quit `less`.

Comment: @SaifulIslam _one per press_? Try press `<space>`. Also will be useful `man less` ;) or at least, press `<h>`.